# One print in a loop

Tags: python

Imagine I have something like:

```
numberlist = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

for number in numberlist:
    print(number)
```

and it would print me every number, right?

But how can I print all these numbers in one line? I expect to get

> 0,1,2,3,4,5 or 0 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: If you just want to see the list you can `print(numberlist)` as well.

Comment: If you Google the phrase *Python print list*, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keyword argument `end` in `print`. Like this:

```
for number in number_list:
    print(number, end=' ')
```

Which, for `number_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`, will give you the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

The default for `end` is `'\n'` which is why each number is printed on a separate line.

Comment: if you're using python 2, you can import the print function with `from __future__ import print_function`. it's called the same way

Answer (score 1):

```
f = " ".join((str(i) for i in numberlist))
print (f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(",".join(str(i) for i in l))
```

or

```
print(" ".join(str(i) for i in l))
```

Comment: correct, but you should hone your formatting

Comment: @MCO fixed the formatting for them. Rabia: nevertheless you should maybe add some explanation about *how* and *why* your code works to improve its long-term value.